# How do apply the Tensorflow and YOLOv7 together for an image classification detector?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo

Currently I am working on developing a source code for an AOI SMT PCB defects detector. I was required to use YOLOv7 and TensorFlow in the code. But it is so confusing me their actual function in the code. I saw tensorflow can be worked independently without YOLO and meanwhile YOLO can do so. As a newbie in deep learning, may I know what are their actual function for the expectation of applying both in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you specify exactly what your use case is ? what is AOI SMT PCB ? what will you provide as input to the model and what do you expect as output ?

Comment: @Alka AOI stands for Automated Optical Inspection, SMT is the advanced technology for PCB design which stands for surface mount technology. The input is the image of PCB board, and the expected output is showing the class of defect and either pass or fail